# PHPExcell. Server sqlite3 cache ethod

Tags: php, caching, phpexcel, php-ini

It look like server doesn't support sqlite3 cache method. What can be reason of that and how to resolve that? In config? Where?[image]

Comment: If the server doesn't support sqlite3, then you need to enable it for your PHP, as per http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.installation.php

Comment: is it supported by php 5.2?

Comment: 1 more q. It's because I've wrote a script and i was testing on my lolcalmachine. XAMPP with php 5.4. That PHPExcell scrit on my machine take 40M of memory. But at main server i imlepented it it takes 188M. Any ideas why?

Comment: SQLite3 has to be enabled/built specifically for PHP < 5.3.0

Comment: Re memory use - 64-bit PHP on server compared with 32-bit PHP in xampp would be one possibility; but there's hundreds of others and only you know the configuration of PHP on your machines

Comment: I added sqlite config. Should that cache method work with that configuration? I'm not server specialist so i have no idea. PHP version is 5.2 at this one. And what u mean saying installed "specifically"?